# 1С 8.3. Как в области макета добавить кликабельную кнопку?

Tags: 1с

Написал такой код:

```
Макет = Обработки.АРМЗаписьНаРемонт.ПолучитьМакет("МакетГоризонтальный");
ОбластьЗаголовок = Макет.ПолучитьОбласть("СтрокаРабочееМесто|КолонкаРабочееМесто"); 
        
НоваяКнопка = ЭлементыФормы.Добавить(Тип("Кнопка"),"ИмяКнопки222"); 
НоваяКнопка.УстановитьДействие("Нажатие", Новый Действие("КоманднаяПанельФормыБыстрыеОтборы"));
        
ОбластьЗаголовок.Параметры.РабочееМесто = НоваяКнопка; 
ТабДок.Вывести(ОбластьЗаголовок);
```

Сама процедура:

```
//Команда для кнопки
Процедура КоманднаяПанельФормыБыстрыеОтборы(Элемент)
Сообщить(111222333);
КонецПроцедуры
```

Кнопка добавляется, но не нажимается, как будто обычный текст в ячейку добавился. Как сделать правильно, чтобы у "кнопки" сработала команда и выдало тестовое: "`111222333`"?

Answer (score 0):

см: https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/1440587/

Вначале нужно создать Команду, затем кнопку, и наконец задать команду кнопке.